# Drag Formula which skips columns referenced in another sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to find out if there a way to take the data below[image] and create a formula that would sum the first 4 values and then copy the 5th and 6th value and add it to page/sheet in the same workbook. Essentially taking 7 columns and minimizing it to 3, like in the image below.
[image]

I have tried dragging the sum formula

```
A1 is =sum(Sheet1!A1:D1)

A2 = =Sheet1!E1

A3 = =Sheet1!F1
```

When I drag it, the formulas I get

```
A1 = =sum(Sheet1!D1:G1) (as opposed to G1:J1)
A2 = =Sheet1!H1 (as opposed to K1)
A3 = =Sheet1!I1 (as opposed to L1)
```

Is there a  way to make the formula to skip cells every time I drag?

I have tried following a few options online such as : https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/410244-dragging-down-formulas-skip-8-rows-reference-another-sheet.html but to no avail

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Excel, or Google Sheets? Also, to copy the data onto another sheet will require VBA.  However, if you can perhaps put that info in another *row* instead, you can probably get a formula. What have you tried so far?  Edit: Wait, it's unclear, do you just want the results in a second page, or only the 5th and 6th values on a second sheet?

Comment: I took my screenshots in Sheets, but need it in Excel. I might not have explained properly. I'm looking to put it onto another page in the same workbook would VBA still be necessary?. I've been trying to follow/manipulate the information I found here. https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/410244-dragging-down-formulas-skip-8-rows-reference-another-sheet.html

Comment: BruceWayne, I have reformulated my question to make it clearer. I am trying to get both the results and the 5th and 6th value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was only 6 columns it wouldn't be too bad to use a separate formula for each column, but if you want to keep pulling the formula across for a lot of columns and the pattern (4 numbers followed by two text cells) remains the same you would need something like this

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(COLUMN()-1,3)+1,
SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!1:1,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)/3,1)*6+1):INDEX(Sheet1!1:1,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)/3,1)*6+4)),
INDEX(Sheet1!1:1,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)/3,1)*6+5),
INDEX(Sheet1!1:1,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)/3,1)*6+6))
```

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

Comment: I have tried editing it to fit my needs, This works in Google Sheets without a problem, but I keep getting an error in Excel =CHOOSE(MOD(COLUMN()-1,2)+1,
SUM(INDEX(Diary!$D2:2,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)/2,1)*9+1):INDEX(Diary!$D2:2,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)/2,1)*9+4)),
SUM(INDEX(Diary!$D2:2,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)/2,1)*9+5):INDEX(Diary!$D2:2,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)/2,1)*9+6)))

Comment: Unfortunately you can't have ranges like D2:2 in Excel, you have to decide how many columns you are going to use and put something like d2:z2